# CKEditor is not working with bootstrap modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, ckeditor

I want to show ckEditor on bootstrap modal but the ckEditor is not opening as shown below. After searching through the internet I have got some solution in a different way like [this link](http://jsfiddle.net/pvkovalev/4PACy/) but I will perform an ajax request hence I have to open the modal using `$('.cia_modal').modal('toggle')`. The above-mentioned solution link does not work for me

Modal Button:

```
<button class="btn btn-info btn-xs cia_modal_btn" data-id="<?php echo $post->post_id; ?>" data-table="post" data-attr="post_id">
   Create New Post
</button>
```

Modal:

```
<!--Modal-->
<div class="modal fade cia_modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header bg-primary">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                    <span class="sr-only">Close</span>
                </button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Create New Post</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">

                <form action="/action_page.php">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <textarea class="ck_editor" name="post" id="" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
                    </div>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
                </form>

            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-white" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<!--End Modal-->
```

Javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

        $(document).on("click", ".modal_btn", function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();

        let cia_modal = $('.cia_modal');
        //Set modal show/hide
        cia_modal.modal('toggle');

        let id = $(this).attr('data-id');
        let table = $(this).attr('data-table');
        let attr = $(this).attr('data-attr');

        //Set Form Data
        let formData = new FormData();
        formData.append('id',id);
        formData.append('table',table);
        formData.append('attr',attr);

        $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: '<?php echo base_url()?>post/create_post',
            data: formData,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            success: function (data) {
               //
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Please help me. Thanks

Comment: You will need to manually initialize CkEditor after modal opens probably. It won't work on hidden elements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume, you are using CKEditor 4.x.

You need to create editor using `CKEDITOR.replace( 'ck_editor' )`, you can do it only on element that is existing inside document. It doesn't matter if it's hidden or not. If your modal is inside DOM, but hidden, then just initialize editor. Otherwise you need to wait until element is appended then call `CKEDITOR.replace`.

Depending on how bootstraps implements `modal.show`. If it's just changes CSS to make it visible, then most likely you can initialize editor at the start of your script, if it adds elements to document, then you need to use some of bootstrap events to create editor in right time. See `shown.bs.modal`: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/modal/#events

Answer (score 1):

Just initialize the editor:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    ClassicEditor.create($('.ck_editor')[0])
        .then( editor => {
            console.log( editor );
        })
        .catch( error => {
            console.log( error );
        });

    $(document).on("click", ".modal_btn", function (e) {
    //....
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

- remove `tabindex="-1"` on Bootstrap Modal
- add `data-bs-focus="false"`

Seems this is not a problem of `ckeditor`, but a bootstrap issue.